# Execute HtttModule for extionsionless URL only

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, httpmodule

I have an httpModule which has to run before an ActionMethod. I dont want that it is executed when a request for an image comes in.

For some reasons I realy need an HttpModule and cant use an ActionFilter

What is the way to do this?

```
public class PostAuthenticateModule : IHttpModule
{

        public void Init(HttpApplication app)
        {
           app.PostAuthenticateRequest += new EventHandler(this.OnEnter);
        }

        private void OnEnter(object source, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {

        }

        private static void Initialize()
        {

        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
        }


}
```

web.config

```
<httpModules>
  <add type="PostAuthenticateModule.PostAuthenticateModule , PostAuthenticateModule" name="PostAuthenticateModule"/>
</httpModules>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using IIS7, have a look at [HttpModule Preconditions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms690693.aspx). Sounds like you want `preCondition="managedHandler"`.

E.g. It could look something like this:

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <remove name="PostAuthenticateModule" />
    <add type="PostAuthenticateModule.PostAuthenticateModule , PostAuthenticateModule" name="PostAuthenticateModule" preCondition="managedHandler" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

HTHs,
Charles

Answer (score 0):

Just inspect the request and short circuit out of the module's execution if it's a static content type. You can't conditionally add a module to the pipeline for some content types.